# How to decorate entity definition in shopware 6

Tags: symfony, symfony5, shopware, shopware6

I would like to decorate entity definition in plugin shopware 6 to add some modifications. I wolud like to change length string field from standard 255 to 4000.

[image: Definition class to change]

my decorate class class with

[image: change length string field]

my config service

```
<service id="MyPlugin\Core\Content\Entities\AttributeTranslationDefinitionDecorator"
        decorates="TestPlugin\Entities\Attribute\Translation\AttributeTranslationDefinition" public="false">
        <argument type="service" id="MyPlugin\Core\Content\Entities\AttributeTranslationDefinitionDecorator.inner" />
    </service>
```

but this not work. I have tried all the ways with pages
https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/plugin-fundamentals/adjusting-service or https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/service_decoration.html

Is it possible to change entity definition in other plugins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Decorating entity definitions is not possible, you can't simply change the existing field definitions of the core entities. Instead you can add an `EntityExtension` if you want to add more fields to an existing entity. Please refer to the [official docs](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/framework/data-handling/add-complex-data-to-existing-entities).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, extending the table will not solve my problem because I need to change the field length. In that case, 
I would have to change the entire plugin if I had to add additional fields via an extension because everything uses it.

Comment: So if I can't change entity definition, the only option is to modify the plugin and upload it to your own repository, right?

Comment: yep that would be the way to go.

Comment: If you use composer to install the plugin, you could use composer-patches https://github.com/vaimo/composer-patches - but I think it would be to contact the plugin vendor and ask them if they accept your patch (maybe you need to make the length configurable)

Comment: I use composer-patches to change the definition and it works! Thanks for solving the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can set the class in the services.xml to the class of your desired adaptation class.
It's more an overwriting than a decoration but it would solve your problem:

```
<service id="TestPlugin\Entities\Attribute\Translation\AttributeTranslationDefinition" 
      class="MyPlugin\Core\Content\Entities\AttributeTranslationDefinitionDecorator" public="false">
    <!-- Original arguments here -->
</service>
```